# How to fix custom messagebox to work in a new thread from parent python pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, signals-slots

I have design my own message box in pyqt5 it worked fine.I remove all except the essential part.Here is my code

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QApplication,QWidget,QPushButton,QDialog,QFrame,QLabel,QTextEdit
from threading import Thread
class messagebox():
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent=parent
        self.parent_width=self.parent.geometry().width()
        self.parent_height=self.parent.geometry().height()
    #This method will flash the messagebox dialog when we click on parent    
    def flash(self,event):
                    QTimer.singleShot(50,lambda:self.toolbar.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue;\n"
        "border-top-left-radius: 20px;\n"
        "border-top-right-radius: 20px;\n"
        "") )
                    QTimer.singleShot(120, lambda:self.toolbar.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;\n"
        "border-top-left-radius: 20px;\n"
        "border-top-right-radius: 20px;\n"
        "") )           
       
    def showinfo(self,title="ShowInfo",msg="Hello,There!"):
        self.value=None
        self.pop = QDialog()
        self.pop.setGeometry(500,200,454,165)
        self.msg=msg
        self.pop.mousePressEvent=self.click
        self.pop.mouseMoveEvent=self.move
        self.frame = QFrame(self.pop)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: #1b1b1b;\n"
            "border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;\n"
            "border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;\n"
            "")
        self.frame.setGeometry(0,30,454,134)
        self.toolbar = QFrame(self.pop)
        self.toolbar.setStyleSheet("background-color:red;\n"
            "border-top-left-radius: 20px;\n"
            "border-top-right-radius: 20px;\n"
            "")
        self.toolbar.setGeometry(0,0,454,30)
        #This makes the window to frameless
        self.pop.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint|Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)                   
        self.pop.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        #self.cover will Cover a frame to its parent entirely
        self.cover=QFrame(self.parent)   
        self.cover.resize(self.parent_width,self.parent_height)
        self.cover.setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent;")
        #you can see the frame by setting background to a color
        self.cover.show()
        self.cover.mousePressEvent=self.flash
        b1 = QPushButton("Ok",self.frame)
        b1.setStyleSheet('''QPushButton {background-color: red;
        border-style: outset;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border-color: beige;
        font: bold 14px;
        min-width: 60px;
        min-height: 25px;
        }''''''QPushButton:pressed{background-color: green;
        border-style: inset;}''')
        b1.move(350,100)
        b1.clicked.connect(self.on_close)
        self.pop.setWindowTitle("Dialog")
        self.pop.setWindowModality(Qt.WindowModal)
        self.pop.exec_()
        return self.value
    def on_close(self):
        self.value=True
        self.cover.deleteLater()
        self.pop.close()
    # move and click  methods are used to drag the dialog   
    def move(self, event):
            if event.buttons() ==Qt.LeftButton:
                    deltax = event.x()- self.xp
                    deltay = event.y() - self.yp
                    x = self.pop.x() + deltax
                    y = self.pop.y() + deltay
                    width,height=int(self.pop.geometry().width()),int(self.pop.geometry().height())
                    self.pop.setGeometry(int(x),int(y),width,height)
    def click(self, event):
           if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
               self.xp=event.x()
               self.yp=event.y()      
def window():
       app = QApplication(sys.argv)
       w = QWidget()
       w.setGeometry(100,100,400,400)
       b = QPushButton(w)
       b.setText("Hello World!")
       b.move(50,50)
       messbox=messagebox(w)
       def run(): 
               h=messbox.showinfo('hello','how r u?')
               print(h) 
       #Thread(target=run).start() 
       b.clicked.connect(run)
       w.setWindowTitle("PyQt Dialog demo")
       w.show()
       sys.exit(app.exec_())    
if __name__ == '__main__':
   window()
```

but the only problem is when I called the messagebox method like `messbox.showinfo()` from a thread it says can't create connection because child is in new thread.I have gone through Various example on this website about worker thread.but I can't understand worker thread  properly.Here i commented out 'Thread part' and call through button click.  Can any one make me understand please?Thank u!!!

Answer (score 0):

The base concept is that UI elements can only be *created* and *accessed* only from the main Qt thread. You cannot create new widgets nor access (read, but most importantly write) their properties from another thread directly.

In order to do so, you have to communicate with the main thread, and Qt signals and slots can be used exactly for this, as Qt is able to manage communications between threads without interfering with its main loop: any communication *from* the foreign thread is queued and is then processed as soon as the main thread allows it. Note that to use signals and slots you should not use a python thread, as it's usually better to subclass from QThread instead. In order to communicate back with the external thread, python Queues can be used.

Note that external threads should only be used when there's some processing that requires some time to be completed (including waiting for external events, such as a response from a network request).

In your case you're not doing such things, so there's no need for another thread (also, your code is quite complex for what it should do, and I won't use it as a base for the following example).

This is a simple example to show how a QThread ("worker") can be implemented.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from queue import Queue

class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    testSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = Queue()

    def run(self):
        self.timer = QtCore.QElapsedTimer()
        timeout = -1
        while True:
            try:
                res = self.queue.get(timeout=.1)
            except:
                # if a timeout has been already set, check if it's expired
                if self.timer.hasExpired(timeout):
                    self.testSignal.emit()
                    self.timer.invalidate()
                    timeout = -1
                continue
            if res is None:
                self.timer.invalidate()
                timeout = -1
            else:
                timeout = res
                self.timer.start()

    def setTimeout(self, timeout):
        self.queue.put(timeout)

    def stopTimeout(self):
        self.queue.put(None)


class Window(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(minimum=1000, maximum=5000, singleStep=500)
        layout.addWidget(self.spinBox)
        self.startButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start')
        layout.addWidget(self.startButton)
        self.stopButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Stop')
        layout.addWidget(self.stopButton)
        self.stopButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.startThreadTimeout)
        self.stopButton.clicked.connect(self.stopThreadTimeout)
        self.resetTimer = QtCore.QTimer(interval=1000, timeout=self.reset)

        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.start()
        self.worker.testSignal.connect(self.flash)

    def startThreadTimeout(self):
        self.reset()
        self.resetTimer.stop()
        self.worker.setTimeout(self.spinBox.value())
        self.startButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.stopButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.label.setText(
            'thread started, finishing in {}ms'.format(self.spinBox.value()))

    def stopThreadTimeout(self):
        # note that this does *not* stop the thread, but only its internal timeout check
        self.worker.stopTimeout()
        self.stopButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.startButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.reset()

    def flash(self):
        self.label.setStyleSheet('background: green')
        self.label.setText('finished')
        self.stopButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.startButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.resetTimer.start()

    def reset(self):
        self.label.setStyleSheet('')
        self.label.setText('')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note that the above code is not very useful, as it's just for learning purposes: obviously you could just use a simple plain QTimer.singleShot in the main thread instead.

Comment: this is little bit complecated can u give example suitable for my code?

Comment: let me just explain what i want!    I want to use this as a messagebox module.suppose i have a download process in my main window there i used thread and for some reason i want to pop the messagebox.Beacause it is inside thread so it throws error or stopped working @musicamante

Comment: No. As explained, all potentially blocking process *must* happen in a separate thread. You should not have a download process in the main window (unless it's already thread safe), and you should not create/access QWidgets from other threads. You have to put the downloading in the thread, and use signals to communicate with the main thread (then show the message box eventually). And, as already said, your example is unnecessarily complex, adapting it to your case would mean to completely rewrite it. Study my code and understand what it does.